# :hover срабатывает без наведения

Tags: css

Градиент должен появляться при наведении, а появляется уже при обновлении страницы, без наведения курсора

```
.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    transition-property: font-size, color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: linear-gradient(#BE04ED, #890BBD);
    font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[linear-gradient:](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

> Так как градиенты относятся к типу данных «image», они могут использоваться только там, где может использоваться «image». По этой причине, linear-gradient() не будет работать в качестве background-color и других свойств, использующих тип данных «color».

```css
.link {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.link:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#BE04ED, #890BBD);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Ссылка</a>
```